# Toggle the "Different Odd & Even Pages" checkbox in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm setting up a set of "boilerplate" Word documents.
All the documents have different Footers for odd and even pages.
The Footers are left- and right-hand biased so that double sided printing will always show important information at the thumb edge of the page.
The document printing default is double sided, so the Header/Footer "Different Odd & Even Pages" box is checked.

However there will be times when a user will want to print single sided.
The box will need to be unchecked.

Each document contains a UserForm to manage features (import external values for Document Variables etc.)
I would like to control the "Different Footer Odds & Even Pages" feature from the UserForm via a pair of Option Buttons.

I've searched multiple site to no avail.

The closest that I gotten is the sample code from the `OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter` Help topic:

```
Set myDoc = Documents("Document1") 
myDoc.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = True 
With myDoc.Sections(1) 
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range _ 
    .InsertAfter "Odd Header" 
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterEvenPages).Range _ 
    .InsertAfter "Even Header" 
End With
```

However I don't want to create footers. I just want to toggle the `PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter` between True and False

I have tried this "stripped down version:

```
'Set OddFootersOnly
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
End With
```

I get the following Error Message

> Run-time error: '4608': Value out of range

Comment: FWIW I set up a small document with three pages and some random text. I set it to use different odd/even headers and footers, with different content. I then ran `ActiveDocument.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = false` and got no error message - changing the property worked. Is there something different about the document(s) you tried running this on? Was a document open in Word when you ran it?